# Symfony 4 : How to Implement OpenId Connect with GuardAuthenticator?

Tags: openid, symfony4, openid-connect

I am trying to implement authentication through OpenId Connect on a Symfony 4 project, in prod environment only.
I created a class extending GuardAuthenticator, and it has to implement several methods : supports, getCredentials, getUser, checkCredentials, onAuthenticationSuccess, etc...

I am using Jumbojett\OpenIDConnectClient.

I cannot find any tutorial or documentation that would help me to structure this GuardAuthenticator class.

OpenId Connect has a heavy protocol(to me), nevertheless Jumbojett\OpenIDConnectClient sorts it well on its own. However I would like to use it properly in the right methods of the GuardAuthenticator.

At the moment, my problem is about structuring correctly the code of my GuardAuthenticator.

The project runs on Linux Debian, php 7.1 and Symfony 4.
My OpenID Provider is Keycloak container on my local machine. However, the project must use a company OpenId Provider that is slightly different from Keycloak. And I can rarely test my code on it.

My class CustomAuthenticator that extends GuardAuthenticator is using OpenIDConnectClient to get the whole process done in method "getCredentials".

When user is authenticated by the OpenId Provider, my class steps into method "onAuthenticationSuccess", and there I store in Session (and in database user object) the ID Token.
After "onAuthenticationSuccess", the script steps into the redirected Controller, and there I login programmatically the user.

After that, I am using method "supports" (of GuardAuthenticator) in order to check the ID Token in the session, and I check several things as JWT Signature (I am not really sure what to check there. And how can I request verification of the session ID Token from my OpenID Provider ?).

I really dont know if it's ok. It seems to work at a certain point.
Is that OK to store ID Token in Session in order to check user authentication?

Any help appreciated.

```php
<?php

//...
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
//..
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\AbstractGuardAuthenticator;

use Jumbojett\OpenIDConnectClient;

class MyGuardAuthenticator extends AbstractGuardAuthenticator
{
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
        $this->openIdConfig = $this->getOpenIdConfig();
        $this->openIdConnector = $this->initOpenIdConnect();
    }
   //...

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        // What should i do here?
        return true;
    }

   //...

    // I check if user has to authenticate against OpenID Provider
    public function supports(Request $request)
    {

        if (isset($_SESSION['id_token'])) {
            $idToken = $_SESSION['id_token'];

            $existingUser = $this->em->getRepository(User::class)
                ->findOneBy(['idToken' => $idToken]);
            if (null === $existingUser) {
                return true;
            }

            // Signature false?
            $isOk = $this->openIdConnector->verifyJWTsignature($idToken);
            if (!$isOk) {
                return true;
            }

            $idTokenPayload = $this->decodeJWT($idToken, 1);
            // expired?
            $now = new \DateTime();
            if ($now->getTimeStamp() > (int) $idTokenPayload->exp) {
                return true;
            }

            //Accept authenticated user
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    // I start the protocol here
    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $this->callProvider();

        return $data->preferred_username;
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {

        $existingUser = $this->em->getRepository(User::class)
            ->findOneBy(['username' => strtoupper($credentials)]);
        if ($existingUser) {
            return $existingUser;
        }
    }

//...

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {

        $existingUser = $this->em->getRepository(User::class)
            ->findOneBy(['username' => $token->getUsername()]);

        if ($existingUser) {
            $existingUser->setIdToken($_SESSION['id_token']);
            $this->em->flush();
        }

        return null;
    }

    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
    {
        return new RedirectResponse(
            '/login/', // might be the site, where users choose their oauth provider
            Response::HTTP_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT
        );
    }

//...

    private function callProvider()
    {
        $this->openIdConnector->setRedirectURL($this->openIdConfig['redirect_uri']);

        $this->openIdConnector->providerConfigParam(
            array(
                'issuer'                                => self::BASE_URL.'/auth/realms/myrealm',
                'authorization_endpoint'                =>
                    self::BASE_URL."/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/auth?scope=openid",
                'token_endpoint'                        =>
                    self::BASE_URL."/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/token",
                'userinfo_endpoint'                     =>
                    self::BASE_URL."/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo",
                'end_session_endpoint'                  =>
                    self::BASE_URL."/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/logout",
                'registration_endpoint'                 =>
                    self::BASE_URL."/auth/realms/myrealm/clients-registrations/openid-connect",
                'jwks_uri'                              =>
                    self::BASE_URL."/auth/realms/myrealm/protocol/openid-connect/certs",
                'token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported' => array('authorization_code'),
            )
        );

        $this->openIdConnector->addScope($this->openIdConfig['scope']);
        $this->openIdConnector->setVerifyPeer(false);
        $this->openIdConnector->authenticate();
        $token = $this->openIdConnector->getIdToken();

        if (null !== $token) {
            $_SESSION['id_token'] = $token;
        }
        $data = $this->openIdConnector->requestUserInfo();

        return $data;
    }
```

Comment: There is a good Guard authenticator example here https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html look closely at what each method returns. For example the `supports()` method should return boolean `true` if the current request route matches (one of)  your authentication route(s) or `false` otherwise, the method is called on every request to see if the authenticator needs to run or not.

Comment: Another good example here used by knpuniversity KnpUOAuth2ClientBundle https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle/blob/master/README.md#authenticating-with-guard

Comment: Actually i have already seen these tutorials. The problem is OpenId Connect has different needs. For instance the example from  symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html show getCredentials with authenticating datas in the request, whereas OpenId connect doesnt let anything nor in the incoming request, neither in a cookie or so.

Comment: And for the second one,  https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle/blob/master/README.md#authenticating-with-guard, I have placed like them the call to ID provider in getCredentials.